# proof of $lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n})=lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n-1}),a_{n})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

prove that $lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n})=lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n-1}),a_{n})$ ($n\in \mathbb N$)

By complete induction on n: (n=1,2 are trivial)

for n=3: let $c=lcm(lcm(a_{1},a_{2}),a_{3})$ and $d=lcm(a_{1},a_{2})$ then $c=lcm(d,a_{3})\Rightarrow d|c$ and $a_{3}|c$ also we have that $a_{1}|d$ and $a_{2}|d$ hence $a_{1}|c$ and $a_{2}|c$ so does this imply that $c=lcm(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})$?

then suppose that $lcm(a_{1},...,a_{k})=lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{k-1}),a_{k})$ $\forall 3\lt k \le n$  I need to prove that $$lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n+1})=lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n}),a_{n+1})$$

$$lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n}),a_{n+1})=lcm(lcm(lcm(a_{1},...a_{n-1}),a_{n},a_{n+1})$$ and repeating this process:

$$lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n}),a_{n+1})=lcm(lcm(...(lcm((lcm(a_{1},a_{2}),a_{3},...,a_{n+1}))...)$$

but the last side of the last equation is just $lcm(lcm(a_{1},a_{2}),a_{3},...a_{n+1})$ but I don´t know if this implies that $$lcm(lcm(a_{1},a_{2}),a_{3},...a_{n+1})=lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n+1})$$

I hope that you can help me with this problem, I would really appreciate it( by the way, I can´t use the prime factorization in this proof)

Comment: Your base case should be the most trivial case you can get away with. There's no need to start at $n=3$ when you can start at $n=2$ (or perhaps even $n=1$!).

Comment: you are right thank you, and is the last part correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this argument is correct as it is. You write $lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n}),a_{n+1})=lcm(lcm(lcm(a_{1},...a_{n-1}),a_{n},a_{n+1})$, but really the induction hypothesis gives you $lcm(lcm(a_{1},...,a_{n}),a_{n+1})=lcm(lcm[lcm(a_{1},...a_{n-1}),a_{n}],a_{n+1})$ (note the parenthesization). Repeating this process would yield $n$ different levels of $lcm$, which makes it not at all clear (without assuming something even stronger than what you're trying to prove) that $lcm(lcm(...(lcm(lcm(a_{1},a_{2}),a_{3}),...),a_{n+1}) = lcm(lcm(a_{1},a_{2}),a_{3},...a_{n+1})$ as you claim.

Unless you have to use induction, I suggest going straight from the definition of $lcm$. It suffices to prove:

- every common multiple of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is also a multiple of $lcm(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$;
- every common multiple of $lcm(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$ and $a_n$ is also a multiple of each of $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$.